# How to get the source and destination of any solana transaction?

Tags: solana-program, web3.js, transactions

For most transaction it is so difficult to find the source and destination of the transaction. as a program in Solana interact with multiple accounts. so how can I get the source and destination of the transaction just like Ethereum they give from and to in their object when I call `web3.eth.getTransaction()`
here is an example: https://explorer.solana.com/tx/qTpMT3jAFkENF9uwkmLF9yX8btZwGyd3fhZb8R4g3LoBrzqVsugEXowdu5UQtJZG3mrjFJHCsEdwHqhqD7oTZbd

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about the transfer of funds, you will have to look at the Transfer inner instructions. There are 6 of them in your example.

Please note for accounts owned by a Program itself, it can adjust the balance without doing a Transfer CPI call so those will not be surfaced.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, if you're fetching the transaction with `getTransaction`, you can look at the pre and post balances.  For example, if this is the response for `getTransaction`:

```
{
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "result": {
    "meta": {
      "err": null,
      "fee": 5000,
      "innerInstructions": [],
      "postBalances": [499998932500, 26858640, 1, 1, 1],
      "postTokenBalances": [],
      "preBalances": [499998937500, 26858640, 1, 1, 1],
      "preTokenBalances": [],
      "rewards": [],
      "status": {
        "Ok": null
      }
    },
    "slot": 430,
    "transaction": { // removed for brevity
    }
  },
  "blockTime": null,
  "id": 1
}
```

In the `"meta"`, you can compare `preBalances` to `postBalances`, and `preTokenBalances` to `postTokenBalances` to see what tokens have moved.

More information about `getTransaction` at https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#gettransaction